# Fedex API giving error value for rates

Tags: php, fedex

why I'm getting this response from FedEx API? when searched everywhere I'm getting response like you wrongly entered your shipper number but i entered it right. I got the response in

> $response = $client ->getRates($request);

```
stdClass Object
(
[HighestSeverity] => WARNING
[Notifications] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [Severity] => WARNING
                [Source] => crs
                [Code] => 556
                [Message] => There are no valid services available. 
                [LocalizedMessage] => There are no valid services available. 
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [Severity] => NOTE
                [Source] => crs
                [Code] => 820
                [Message] => The destination state/province code has been changed.  
                [LocalizedMessage] => The destination state/province code has been changed.  
            )

    )

[TransactionDetail] => stdClass Object
    (
        [CustomerTransactionId] =>  *** Rate Available Services Request v7 using PHP ***
    )

[Version] => stdClass Object
    (
        [ServiceId] => crs
        [Major] => 7
        [Intermediate] => 0
        [Minor] => 0
    )
)
```

I requested shipment like below

```
[RequestedShipment] => Array
        (
            [DropoffType] => REGULAR_PICKUP
            [ShipTimestamp] => 2015-04-15T13:19:32+05:30
            [Shipper] => Array
                (
                    [Address] => Array
                        (
                            [StreetLines] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 1202 Chalet Ln
                                )

                            [City] => 
                            [StateOrProvinceCode] => AR
                            [PostalCode] => 72601
                            [CountryCode] => US
                        )

                )

            [Recipient] => Array
                (
                    [Address] => Array
                        (
                            [PostalCode] => 97005
                            [CountryCode] => US
                        )

                )

            [ShippingChargesPayment] => Array
                (
                    [PaymentType] => SENDER
                    [Payor] => Array
                        (
                            [AccountNumber] => 510087623
                            [CountryCode] => US
                        )

                )

            [RateRequestTypes] => LIST
            [PackageCount] => 1
            [PackageDetail] => INDIVIDUAL_PACKAGES
            [RequestedPackageLineItems] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [Weight] => Array
                                (
                                    [Value] => 1.25
                                    [Units] => LB
                                )

                            [Dimensions] => Array
                                (
                                    [Length] => 100
                                    [Width] => 100
                                    [Height] => 100
                                    [Units] => IN
                                )

                        )

                )

        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things caught my attention with your request:

1. The recipient address doesn't contain a state value. I'm not completely sure whether it's required by FedEx, but many carriers do require the state code.
2. The package dimensions are 100x100x100. According to http://images.fedex.com/us/services/pdf/packaging/GrlPkgGuidelines_fxcom.pdf, this exceeds the max. girth restriction and thus you would need to use FedEx Freight, which is a different API. This would explain the "no valid services" error.

Comment: Thanks simon. That was the problem, dimension i given was wrong

Answer (score 0):

For me, issue was that the FedexRateServiceRequest requires Zip, CountryCode AND State. Without state I got the same error.

```
rate_request.RequestedShipment.Recipient.Address.StateOrProvinceCode = 'CA'
```